# Firefox prevents POST requests

Tags: ajax, firefox, post, vaadin, resin

I have a web application that uses xhr POST to upload files, the issue here is that when the web application sends another ajax POST request (not to upload data) the request is blocked until the first one is finished, in the firefox developer tools, the request will be an indeterminate state until the first one is finished, this was not replicated in Chrome, and not replicated with Firefox across all server deployment (since the application is used with different server setups)

I have overriden the following properties in Firefox to have more concurrent connections, but this didnt resolve the issue also.

Network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server
Network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-proxy

What are the possible causes of this, and how can i fix it, the web application uses Caucho Resin, and the Client side was created using Vaadin framework.

Comment: May you add a Question :-)
Do you want to fix Firefox or change the vaadin-config or the tomcat application server?
Welcome at Stackoverflow.

Comment: updated the question to be more clear